# iPhone time sync, mobile operator vs. NTP

Tags: iphone, ntp

There is very little information how the iPhone syncs time.

From what I gather the **iPhone uses the mobile operator's time** through some protocol.

There is a general problem when the operator supplies the wrong time. Mine supplies 7 minutes behind.

**My mac syncs using NTP** and this is by default, which is far more accurate and dependable.

Unfortunately I haven't found any native way to sync the iPhone with NTP standalone. Even if there is an app, I'll have to start it and this makes it far too unusable.

Sometimes when linked to iTunes my iPhone will sync the time with my mac's time. But not always. I cannot find what is the pattern.

Solution one: disable automatic time sync. I don't like it.
Is there a solution for NTP sync? A native, easy-to-use, setup-and-forget solution?